# Taking multiple integers on the same line as input from the user in python

Tags: python, python-2.x

I know how to take a single input from user in `python 2.5`:

```
raw_input("enter 1st number")
```

This opens up one input screen and takes in the first number. If I want to take a second input I need to repeat the same command and that opens up in another dialogue box.
How can I take two or more inputs together in the same dialogue box that opens such that:

```
Enter 1st number:................
enter second number:.............
```

Comment: `raw_input` opens a dialogue box? How (e.g. in what enviroment) are you running your programs?

Comment: What i meant by box was the simple small window that opens up to take raw_input

Comment: Yes, I figured that. I'm still surprised because `raw_input` should just write the prompt to `sys.stdout` and read the input from `sys.stdin`, and those are usually a terminal, another program's output or a file. If there's GUI happening when you do it, that'd be *very* unusual enviroment.

Comment: Note that in Python 3, `raw_input` has been renamed `input`.

Answer (score 17):

This might prove useful:

```
a,b=map(int,raw_input().split())
```

You can then use 'a' and 'b' separately.

Answer (score 16):

How about something like this?

```
user_input = raw_input("Enter three numbers separated by commas: ")

input_list = user_input.split(',')
numbers = [float(x.strip()) for x in input_list]
```

(You would probably want some error handling too)

Comment: This is a really nice way to take input from the user.

Answer (score 4):

Or if you are collecting many numbers, use a loop

```
num = []
for i in xrange(1, 10):
    num.append(raw_input('Enter the %s number: '))

print num
```

Answer (score 2):

My first impression was that you were wanting a looping command-prompt with looping user-input inside of that looping command-prompt. (Nested user-input.) Maybe it's not what you wanted, but I already wrote this answer before I realized that. So, I'm going to post it in case other people (or even you) find it useful.

You just need nested loops with an input statement at each loop's level.

For instance,

```
data=""
while 1:
    data=raw_input("Command: ")
    if data in ("test", "experiment", "try"):
        data2=""
        while data2=="":
            data2=raw_input("Which test? ")
        if data2=="chemical":
            print("You chose a chemical test.")
        else:
            print("We don't have any " + data2 + " tests.")
    elif data=="quit":
        break
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 2):

1. `a, b, c = input().split()     # for space-separated inputs`
2. `a, b, c = input().split(",")  # for comma-separated inputs`

Comment: Provide the explanation of your code and how it solves the Problem?

Comment: whenever you want to take multiple inputs in a single line with the inputs seperated with spaces then use the first case .And when the inputes are seperated by comma then use the seconfd case . You implement this to shell or any ide and see the working ..@MittalPatel

Comment: This will fail horribly if the user doesn't input exactly the required number of fields.

Answer (score 2):

You can read multiple inputs in Python 3.x by using below code which splits input string and converts into the integer and values are printed

```
user_input = input("Enter Numbers\n").split(',')
#strip is used to remove the white space. Not mandatory
all_numbers = [int(x.strip()) for x in user_input]
for i in all_numbers:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the below to take multiple inputs separated by a keyword

```
a,b,c=raw_input("Please enter the age of 3 people in one line using commas\n").split(',')
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to practice by using a single liner,
Syntax:

> list(map(inputType, input("Enter").split(",")))

Taking multiple integer inputs:

```
   list(map(int, input('Enter: ').split(',')))
```

[image]

Taking multiple Float inputs:

```
list(map(float, input('Enter: ').split(',')))
```

[image]

Taking multiple String inputs:

```
list(map(str, input('Enter: ').split(',')))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
List_of_input=list(map(int,input (). split ()))
print(List_of_input)
```

It's for Python3.

Answer (score 0):

Python and all other [*imperative* programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_programming) execute one command after another. Therefore, you can just write:

```
first  = raw_input('Enter 1st number: ')
second = raw_input('Enter second number: ')
```

Then, you can operate on the variables `first` and `second`. For example, you can convert the strings stored in them to *int*egers and multiply them:

```
product = int(first) * int(second)
print('The product of the two is ' + str(product))
```

Comment: Thats right but isnt this going to open up two boxes...how can i enter both numbers in one box? like embedding both raw_input commands into one dialogue box at the same time

Comment: @user899714 In the default cpython environment, `raw_input` has no graphical user interface. You seem to be using a graphical/educational Python environment. Can you tell us the name of that environment?

Comment: Actually i haven't used one yet. i was wondering if i could enhance the look of how i take input from user without getting into the hassle of using a graphical environment just by modifying/changing raw_input command...But i guess it isn't possible.

Comment: PythonWin opens up a dialog box when using raw_input.  At least pywin32 build 212 does.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, you can input multiple values comma separately (as jcfollower mention in his solution). But if you want to do it explicitly, you can proceed in following way.
I am taking multiple inputs from users using a for loop and keeping them in items list by splitting with ','.

```
items= [x for x in raw_input("Enter your numbers comma separated: ").split(',')]

print items
```

Comment: probably you would like to add a textual explanation to your solution

Comment: Thank you. I have added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    j= int(line[0])
    e= float(line[1])
    t= str(line[2])
```

For details, please review,

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Python_Programming/Input_and_Output#Standard_File_Objects

Answer (score 0):

Split function will split the input data according to whitespace.

```
data = input().split()
name=data[0]
id=data[1]
marks = list(map(datatype, data[2:]))
```

name will get first column, id will contain second column and marks will be a list which will contain data from third column to last column.

Answer (score 0):

A common arrangement is to read one string at a time until the user inputs an empty string.

```py
strings = []
# endless loop, exit condition within
while True:
    inputstr = input('Enter another string, or nothing to quit: ')
    if inputstr:
        strings.append(inputstr)
    else:
        break
```

This is Python 3 code; for Python 2, you would use `raw_input` instead of `input`.

Another common arrangement is to read strings from a file, one per line. This is more convenient for the user because they can go back and fix typos in the file and rerun the script, which they can't for a tool which requires interactive input (unless you spend a lot more time on basically building an editor into the script!)

```py
with open(filename) as lines:
    strings = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in lines]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
n = int(input())
for i in range(n):
    i = int(input())
```

If you dont want to use lists, check out this code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 methods which can be used:

1. This method is using list comprehension as shown below:

   ```
    x, y = [int(x) for x in input("Enter two numbers: ").split()] # This program takes inputs, converts them into integer and splits them and you need to provide 2 inputs using space as space is default separator for split.

    x, y = [int(x) for x in input("Enter two numbers: ").split(",")] # This one is used when you want to input number using comma.
   ```
2. Another method is used if you want to get inputs as a list as shown below:

   ```
    x, y = list(map(int, input("Enter the numbers: ").split())) # The inputs are converted/mapped into integers using map function and type-casted into a list
   ```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
print ("Enter the Five Numbers with Comma")

k=[x for x in input("Enter Number:").split(',')]

for l in k:
    print (l)
```

Answer (score -1):

How about making the input a list. Then you may use standard list operations.

```
a=list(input("Enter the numbers"))
```

Comment: @UmeshYadav Your proposed edit would have turned this into a duplicate of other answers here. This should probably simply be downvoted, and eventually deleted.

Answer (score -1):

```
# the more input you want to add variable accordingly
x,y,z=input("enter the numbers: ").split( ) 
#for printing 
print("value of x: ",x)
print("value of y: ",y)
print("value of z: ",z)

#for multiple inputs    
#using list, map
#split seperates values by ( )single space in this case

x=list(map(int,input("enter the numbers: ").split( )))

#we will get list of our desired elements 

print("print list: ",x)
```

hope you got your answer :)

Comment: This is just a combination of several existing answers.