# How do I gather user numerical input into a list in Python?

Tags: python, list, input

I'm new to Python and am trying to make a simple program to calculate mean median and mode from numbers input by user. So far I have:

```
num=[]
UserNumbers=int(input("Enter number sequence separated by spaces: "))
num.append(UserNumbers)
print (num)
```

I want the user to be able to input multiple int's separated by spaces, however my code only accepts one number. The mean/median/mode part shouldn't be hard as I'm just going to use statistics package in 3.4; just need help with gathering input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to parse the answer if you want it this way.

```
UserNumbers=input("Enter number sequence separated by spaces: ")
nums = [int(i) for i in UserNumbers.split()]
```

EDIT:

[Duplicate of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one line:

```
user_numbers = [int(num) for num in raw_input
                ("Enter number sequence separated by spaces: ").split()]
```

Notes:

- Read about [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)
- Read about [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)
- [List comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)