# Attribute errors in Python with string object?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
series = input("Please enter 10 numbers: ")
series.remove(5)
```

When I try to remove all occurrences of 5, I get the following error:

```
   line 2, in <module> series.remove(5)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

What is an attribute error and why does this happen?

Comment: `series` is not a list, it is a string. Strings don't have a `remove` method.

Comment: how do you turn     series into a list? is it     series=[]

Comment: You'll have to split the string (requiring the user to use some kind of delimiter for you to split on), or use a loop to ask the user for each number separately. See [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7378091) for an example of the splitting approach.

Comment: @StevenSummers thank you ` series = input("Please enter 10 numbers: ")
series_list = series.split(',')
series_list.remove(5)` 
now i get this error: 
_ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list_

Comment: @MartijnPieters thank you

Comment: @user5437964: splitting still gives you separate strings, there is no integer `5` in your list, at best only `'5'` (a string) is there.

Answer (score 0):

Strings doesn't have a `remove` method. If you want to eliminate every occurrence in a string you should use replace

```
series = input("Please enter 10 numbers: ")
series.replace('5','') #Here 5 is a string (substring of series you want to replace)
```

But his seems more like you want a list of numbers, better do:

```
series = map(int, input("Please enter 10 numbers: ").split(separator))
series.remove(5) #Here is a number
```