# How can we take more than one input values in python language by using comma or space between two numbers or character

Tags: python

How can we take more than one input values in python language by using comma or space between two numbers or character??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
m, n = raw_input().strip().split(" ")
```

In the above example, the two values need to be input separated by a `space`.

If you prefer using a comma for whatever reason, change the `split(" ")` to `split(",")`

> note that the above example is for `python2`.

For use in `python3`, change the `raw_input()` to `input()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply try:

In `Python2`:

```
i = raw_input("Whatever:")

u , c= i.split()
```

In `Python3`:

```
i = input("Whatever:")

u ,c = i.split()
```

Hope this helps :)