# Solution for Matlab equivalent inputdlg in Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

I have the following questions:

**Question 1**

Unlike in Matlab where I can use user input command `inputdlg` and immediately converting it double by bellow to commands.How same thing can be implemented in Python 2.7 without writing many lines of code

**My Matlab code**:

```
io_config = inputdlg('Enter I/O config- 1: Input1, 2 : Input2Binary','ioconfig');
io_config=str2double(io_config);
```

**Question 2**

How to use index in python similar to Matlab

**My Matlab code**

```
temp=1;
for index1=1:length(navtime);
for index2=temp:length(time);
diff = navtime(index1) - time(index2)
```

I have time and *navtime* column vector in input `csv` file. How can I implement same in Python.

Many of you might be finding it easy but I am stuck at this point for 
quite some time. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: There are a lot of posts about that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Comment: Okay .thanks for the suggestion . I will check it