# Python - How do I use a scanner multiple times in a loop?

Tags: python

I am trying to learn Python and I was trying to test what I just learned with a simple program. The program asks the user how many numbers they want to enter and then the program will use a loop to store the amount of numbers and find the average.

```
numberOfTimes = int(input("How many numbers do you want to use today? "))

count = 0

while(count < numberOfTimes):
    numberInput = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    count += 1

print((numberInput + numberInput + numberInput) / (count))
```

How do I get `numberInput` to store each variable?

Comment: Do you really need to store each number? You can use a running total.

Comment: You could use a [list](https://developers.google.com/edu/python/lists)

Comment: If you don't want to sum them in the loop, you can make a List variable and append numberInput to it inside the loop. Then after the loop you can do what you want with those inputted numbers (sum, etc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Comment: Conceptually understand list, where you can store as many numbers as the user enters. Logically you don't need to store all numbers, just the total to calculate average (/count)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to store all the numbers, just sum them as you go:

```
count = 0
total = 0

while(count < numberOfTimes):
    total += int(input("Enter the number: "))
    count += 1

print(total / count)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could declare a variable like `totalNumber` just above your loop and then all you have to do in the loop is the following:

`totalNumber += int(input("Enter your number: ")`

Answer (score 0):

Congrats for learning python, it's a great language.

So if you want to have the biggest flexibility you should save your numbers in a list.

A list in python behaves like a classically known array list (e.g. in java) because it can be accessed by index and it can be extended and has no fixed length.

So using a list you can add every number into a list:

```
numbers = list()

while(count < numberOfTimes):
    numberInput = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    numbers.append(numberInput)
    count += 1
```

Since you are now using a list of variable length you could also use the lengths (`len(mylist)` list to determine the end of the while loop:

```
numbers = list()

while(len(numbers) < numberOfTimes):
    numberInput = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    numbers.append(numberInput)
```

Combining all these steps:

```
numberOfTimes = int(input("How many numbers do you want to use today? "))
numbers = list()

while(len(numbers) < numberOfTimes):
    numberInput = int(input("Enter the number: "))
    numbers.append(numberInput)

print( sum(numbers) / len(numbers) )
```

I added a little functionality to make it easier e.g. `sum(numbers)` is a build in function than sums up all the integers in the list and `len(numbers)` again replacing the counter.

Executing the program like that will show you quite quick, that you only get integer numbers as result which are not the correct average, here a you need to know that dividing two integers in python results in an integer which is most of the time not the result you want. There is a trick, cast one of the numbers (or both) to be floats, then divide:

```
average = float(sum(numbers)) / len(numbers)
print(average)
```

If you want to try some more steps you could e.g. get rid of the first question to ask for an amount of numbers by jumping out of the while loop depending on the content you type in:

```
print("Write some numbers, I will calculate the average. Finish with 'enter'")
numbers = list()

while(True):
    myinput = raw_input("Enter a number: ")
    if myinput == '':
        break
    numberInput = int(myinput)
    numbers.append(numberInput)

average = float(sum(numbers)) / len(numbers)
print(average)
```

The changes are this time: use `raw_input` instead of `input` which would be recommended, the while loop runs for ever if it doesn't get to the `break` which is executed if you don't give any input but just hit enter and the initial question for the count obviously is missing.