# Consider the following code

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
import sys
n = input()
a = []
for i in range(n):
    temp = input()
    a[i].append(temp)
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = a[i] - 1
    if a[i] ==0 and a[i+1] != 0 or a[i-1] != 0:
        print "NO"
        break
print "YES"
for i in range(n):
    print a[i]
```

code is running without any error but is giving error after the input

```
2
2 2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 5, in ?
    temp = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    2 2
     ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

why is it not working and giving EOF error?

Comment: Because `input()` can not handle the fact that a pipe stops. You better iterate over `sys.stdin` in that case.

Comment: And `a[i].append(temp)` does not makes sense here.

Comment: Calling [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: if you want to enter multiple values in an array you should use 
`a = map(int, input().split())`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Taking multiple inputs from user in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

`a[i]` doesn't work because the list `a` is only one array. If the array had lists inside of it, then `a[i]` would work.

As long as there are enough lists inside of the array to allow the for loop to run.

So, before you run the first for loop, you need to append `n` arrays ([]) to `a`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to remove [i] from a[i].append(temp)

```
import sys
n = input('Please input n: ')
a = []
for i in range(n):
    temp = input('Please input temp: ')
    a.append(temp)
for i in range(n):
    a[i] = a[i] - 1
    if a[i] == 0 and a[i+1] != 0 or a[i-1] != 0:
        print "NO"
        break
print "YES"
for i in range(n):
    print a[i]
```

and result is:

```
Please input n: 5
Please input temp: 1
Please input temp: 2
Please input temp: 3
Please input temp: 4
Please input temp: 5
NO
YES
0
2
3
4
5
```

if I understand correctly your task.