# From a parameter of tuple, trying to find two sums

Tags: python, sum, tuples

One adds every other number starting with first number and the second sum starts with the second number. 
Example;

```
Tuple= (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
Sum1= 1+3+5+7
Sum2= 2+4+6+8
```

Here's what I have so far:

```
def everyOtherSumDiff(eg):
    a=0
    b=0
    for i in (eg, 2):
        a+=i

    return a

eg=(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)        
print(everyOtherSumDiff(eg))
```

I'm not sure how to get the tuple from a user input and I haven't worked a lot with tuples so I'm not sure how to add them together going every other, especially having to go from a different starting point.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You get the values from tuples the same way as you get values from lists.  So within `everyOtherSumDiff` code as if parameter `eg` is a list.

Comment: _I'm not sure how to get the tuple from a user input and I haven't worked a lot with tuples so I'm not sure how to add them together going every other, especially having to go from a different starting point._ Can you be more specific? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: _I'm not sure how to get the tuple from a user input_ That part of the question is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python, _I haven't worked a lot with tuples so I'm not sure how to add them together going every other, especially having to go from a different starting point_ and that is unclear.

Answer (score 4):

You can use slicing syntax [start:stop:step] for this

```
>>> tup = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
>>> sum(tup[0::2])  # sum every second element, starting index 0
16
>>> sum(tup[1::2])  # sum every second element, starting index 1
20
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to build upon covfefe19's answer and add the tuple part:

```
my_tuple = () #I define the tuple
user_input = input('Please write a series of number one at a time. Press q to quit') #I #define the input statement
my_tuple = (int(user_input),) #I add the number from the input into the tuple as a number

while user_input.isdigit(): #Here I use the "isdigit()" to create the condition for the #while loop. As long as the input is a digit the input will keep poppin up
    user_input = input()

    if user_input.isdigit():
        my_tuple = my_tuple + (int(user_input),) #I add the input as a number to the tuple
    else:
        pass #if input not a number, then pass and go on the next part of the function
else:
    print('You have quit the input process')
    every_second = sum(my_tuple[0::2]) ## This is covfefe19's solution to tuple
    every_other = sum(my_tuple[1::2]) ## so as this
    print(my_tuple)
    print(every_second, '\n', every_other) ##This prints the answer
```

Hope this helps a bit with the making of inputs and storing it into tuples!

As you can see, you have to call the tuple created and add the input as a tuple `(user_input,)`. This will add each value inserted into the input into the last index of `my_tuple`

Comment: Why not just get all the input at once?

Comment: To be honest, it just hadn't occurred to me. This format seemed "the safest"