# How do i convert all the variables into an int straightaway

Tags: python-3.x, input, split, int

`a,b,c = input(a,b,c).split()`

would need a way to immediately convert a,b,c into int without having to do something like

`a = int(a)`
`b = int(b)`
`c = int(c)`

please help :)

Comment: did you read the documentation of input()?  `input( a,b,c)` is invalid code. Where is your real problem?

Comment: So this is the reason you downvote the answer?

Comment: Duplicate: [taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7378091/taking-multiple-inputs-from-user-in-python)

Comment: Fine, though the list is just a demostration that all iterable works.

Answer (score 0):

```
l = input().split(',')
l = [ int(i) for i in l ]
a, b, c = *l
```

Run the code and enter 3 integers separated by ',' then a b and c will contain the 3 integers